# Classic merge sort

Tags: python, python-2.x, mergesort

Here is my code for classic merge sort. My question is, each time I create a new list `result` to merge sub-parts, is there a way to save the space -- not creating a new list `result`?

Besides my above major question, any advice for code improvement, bugs, performance (algorithm time complexity perspective) is highly appreciated.

```
def merge_sort(numbers, start, end):
    if not numbers:
        return None
    if start == end:
        return [numbers[start]]
    mid = (start + end) // 2
    sub_part1 = merge_sort(numbers, start, mid)
    sub_part2 = merge_sort(numbers, mid+1, end)
    result = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(sub_part1) and j < len(sub_part2):
        if sub_part1[i] <= sub_part2[j]:
            result.append(sub_part1[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(sub_part2[j])
            j += 1

    if i < len(sub_part1) and j == len(sub_part2):
        result.extend(sub_part1[i:])
    if j < len(sub_part2) and i == len(sub_part1):
        result.extend(sub_part2[j:])

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print merge_sort([1,4,2,5,6,8,3,4,0], 0, 8)
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Step 1:

I would change the computation of `mid` to:

```
mid = start + (start - end) // 2
```

Although python won't give you the wrong answer if you use yours, you theoretically lose performance with lots of elements (>2<sup>63</sup>).

Also, the code when you are doing the final part of the merge can be simplified to:

```
if i < len(sub_part1):
    result.extend(sub_part1[i:])
else:
    result.extend(sub_part2[j:])
```

Which is just cleaner. This can be further improved to:

```
result.extend(sub_part1[i:])
result.extend(sub_part2[j:])
```

because the cost of the if statement is more than the cost of appending nothing.

#### Step 2:

One of the tricks most implementations of mergesort use is they call a slightly different version of themselves at the beginning who's signature is:

```
def merge_sort(numbers, start, end, result):
    ...
```

The advantage of this is that you can alternate which list is your numbers and which list stores the result to avoid allocation or appending to arrays. (because you merge onto an existing result array).

Finally, if you want a fast implementation that feels like cheating (why I love Python), you can use this version from wikibooks.

```
from heapq import merge

def mergesort(w):
    if len(w)<2:
        return w
    else:    
        mid=len(w)//2
        return merge(mergesort(w[:mid]), mergesort(w[mid:]))
```

Comment: Thanks Dex' ter, love all of your comments and vote up. Could you elaborate a bit more what do you mean `you theoretically lose performance with lots of elements (>2^63)`? And why `mid = start + (start - end) // 2` is faster?

Comment: BTW, Dex' ter, followed your advice and write some new code and post here, still do not figure out how to use `numbers` without using `result`, if you have any ideas, it will be great. My new post here => http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/classic-merge-sort-part-2

Comment: The short answer is that if you have a lot of elements, `start+end` can be greater than `2^64`, which will make python switch to slower big integer math. The bigger reason this is important is because if you are in a language like C `(start + end) // 2` can be negative leading to very bad things. This actually was a bug in Python's Sort for several years.

Comment: Thanks Oscar, is it possible to have only one copy or in-place do merge sort? I am not sure if `merge` will create a copy -- each time when doing a merge from two smaller array into a a bigger one?

Comment: It is possible to both do `merge` with one copy, and in place. In place `mergesort` is really hard, and tends to be `O(nlog^2(n))` rather than `O(nlog(n))`. One copy on the other hand is the way most `mergesorts` used in real life work. The basic way is to have 2 arrays and copy back and forth when you are merging.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to reduce memory usage when mergesorting an array. However you **can** reduce a number of allocations and handle the task with just **one copy** of the input array. The general outline:

- for an input array `A` and indices range `start` through `end` create an array `B` and copy all items of `A` to `B`,
- double-array-merge-sort from `B` range `start` through `end` to a respective range of `A`,
- drop/forget/destroy array `B`;

where 'double-array-merge-sort from a range of `S` to `D`' is implemented as:

- if a given range of `S` is longer than 1 item:

  - find a midpoint of `S` range to define two halves,
  - double-array-merge-sort from a left half of `D` to a left half of `S`,
  - double-array-merge-sort from a right half of `D` to a right half of `S`,
  - merge both halves of `S` range into the respective `D` range
- else

  - nothing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the advice CiaPan, and vote up. It seems from the reply of Dex' ter, we can re-use the same array -- even no need to make another copy? Any comments on that?

Comment: Thanks CiaPan, what do you mean `double-array-merge-sort`? Especially confused by what do you mean`double`? And for `destroy` -- I think for C/C++ there is `free` or `delete`, but for Python, how/what do you mean `destroy`?

Comment: Read the whole answer, not just the first two sentences, and you'll see the 'double-array-merge-sort' mentioned in the first part, is a routine described in the second part.

Comment: I gave it a name 'double-array-merge-sort` because it sorts with merging procedure and it is designed to sort arrays. And it utilizes _two_ initially equivalent arrays (hence 'double array') to accomplish the task.

Comment: I didn't say `destroy` – I said 'drop/forget/destroy'. Please note I didn't mention nor used any specific programming language. I have even explicitly pointed out it's a 'general outline'. You are an implementor, and it's up to you to choose appropriate way of allocating and disposing temporary objects (be it `dispose()` in Pascal, `free()` in C, `delete[]` in C++ or just dropping for a garbage collector in Java)...

Comment: As for your first comment: **1.** The other answer was given by Oscar Smith, not by Dex' ter; user Dex' ter improved formatting of it. **2.** Oscar Smith never said you can reuse the same array. He shows some nice improvements of the code, but none of them works _in situ_.

Comment: Thanks CiaPan, love all of your comments and vote up and I have posted some new code here => http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/classic-merge-sort-part-2, wondering if the implementation I posted there is the same you described for the `double-array-merge-sort`? I think it is the same if I understand your method correctly. But if you have comments on my new code, it will be great.

Comment: BTW, you mentioned both `A` and `B`, also `S` and `D` in your examples, just a bit confused since I think in each merge operation of `double-array-merge-sort`, you need to create one copy? Or you mean you only need one copy of original data? If you could show some code, it will be great.

Comment: I suggest learning some basic programming, e.g. [subroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine), their [local variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) and [parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)). But that's not what CodeReview site is for, so EOT.